# Webdriver cssSelector of element with quotes inside of value

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, css-selectors

I cannot figure out how to select an element  by cssSelector in my WebDriver test.

I will appreciate your help in solving this problem.

According to webdriver css selector syntax it has to be something like

```
WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[ng-click='session='my_portcalls'']"))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar hurdle using Protractor/WebDriverJS.

What worked for me was the following:

element(by.css('[ng-click="changePanel(\'delete\')"]'));

In the html the element looks like the following:

.... ng-click="changePanel('delete')" ...

So single escaping works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes inside the attribute value for the selector to be valid:

```
WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[ng-click='session=\\'my_portcalls\\'']"))
```

Comment: To escape the ' character you need only one \ character. That's how I remember it.

Comment: @Gabriel Porumb: Yes, the additional \ is there to escape the first \ within the entire selector string (including the `a`).